# ASP.Net (VB) Textbox - Set Default Text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am writing an ASP.Net web application and am trying to set a default text value to a TextBox on a page load.

I want the page to load with a text value already entered into the TextBox. Unlike a placeholder I want it to be physical text in the TextBox. No matter what I try the closest I can get to is having the value of the TextBox to what I want but not the actual text.

I have been scouring the web looking for an answer and have had no luck. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" Text="My default text" />
```

Or in code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
       txtBox.Text = "My default text"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="hello" />
```

vb.net code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
   txtBox.Text = "hello"
End If
```

End Sub